# ¿Para qué sirve module.exports?

Tags: javascript

Necesito de su ayuda para saber cómo se utiliza `module.exports` en JavaScript.

Comment: Bienvenido @Etelvina a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 10):

Los módulos en JavaScript desde la versión **ES6**, se utilizan para poder exportar funciones o grupos de funciones así como objetos, constantes y variables de un archivo `.js`a otro. De modo que deberás usar la palabra reservada `exports` para lograrlo; los módulos serán funcionales bajo un ambiente de trabajo del lado del servidor con NodeJS.

**EXPLICACIÓN DEL ESCENARIO**

El archivo `.js` que exporta deberá tener una sintaxis similar a la siguiente

```
const IVA = 16;

module.exports = IVA
```

El archivo `.js` que recibe la data exportada, la procesa con una sintaxis similar a la siguiente

```
const ivaMexico = require("./nombrearchivo.js")
```

**EJEMPLO 1**

Tienes un archivo llamado `app1.js` donde tienes una función que devuelve la fecha de este modo

```
"use strict";

let fecha = () => {
    return new Date();
}

console.log(fecha())
```

Al ejecutar el comando en consola:

```
node app1.js
```

Me devolverá lo siguiente

> 2019-03-23T18:15:47.977Z

Sin embargo si yo quiero reutilizar esta misma función pero ahora en `app2.js` obtendré un mensaje de error como este

> ReferenceError: fecha is not defined

Pues dentro del contexto del archivo `app2.js` esta función no existe

Entonces deberé hacer en `app1.js` lo siguiente, para poder recuperar a dicha función en `app2.js`

Al final del archivo agrego la siguiente línea

```
module.exports = fecha()
```

y ahora en `app2.js` invoco a dicha función que exporté de este modo

```
let nuevaFecha = require("./app1")
```

Donde estoy asignando a la variable `nuevaFecha` lo que el modulo acaba de exportar y ahora para imprimir dicho valor hago lo siguiente

```
console.log(nuevaFecha)
```

Lo cual me devuelve lo siguiente

> 2019-03-23T18:20:34.849Z

**EJEMPLO 2**

Pero que pasa si necesito exportar mas de una función?

Imagina que de nuevo dentro de `app1.js` tenemos la siguiente estructura de código

```
"use strict";

let fecha = () => {
    return new Date();
}

let saludo = () => {
    return "hola";
}

let despedida = () => {
    return "adios";
}
```

Entonces supondríamos que para exportarlas debemos hacer lo siguiente, al final de nuestro documento

```
module.exports = { fecha, saludo, despedida }
```

Y ahora dentro de `app2.js` hacer lo siguiente

```
let nuevaFecha = require("./app1")

console.log(nuevaFecha)
```

Pero lo anterior nos devolvería como resultado lo siguiente

```
{ fecha: [Function: fecha],
  saludo: [Function: saludo],
  despedida: [Function: despedida] }
```

Entonces cambia el como debemos acceder a los valores que cada función retorna, reformulando el código de `app2.js` del modo siguiente

```
console.log(nuevaFecha.fecha())
console.log(nuevaFecha.saludo())
console.log(nuevaFecha.despedida())
```

Lo cual en consola nos devolverá lo siguiente

> 2019-03-23T18:31:12.880Z
>   hola
>   adios

Es decir a la variable `nuevaFecha` le tuvimos que indicar de manera explícita a que función acceder para devolver el contenido específico de cada una de ellas por medio de la sintaxis de `variable.nombreFuncion()`

Aqui te dejo [una fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export) para seguir consultando al respecto