# ¿Alternativa javascript a include en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs

Estoy empezando ha aprender javascript a utilizar NodeJS, y me gustaria saber la alternativa que hay en javascript para hacer:

```
<?php include('header.html'); ?>
```

He estado mirando en Google y demas y he visto Handlebars.js, no estoy seguro si esa sería la mejor opción, por eso pregunto por aquí.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: módulos en JS, revisa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248274/para-que-sirve-module-exports-reci%C3%A9n-empiezo-con-javascript/248282#248282

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/5587982) de SO en inglés, muestra varias formas de hacerlo, según la versión de navegador, o usando ciertas librerías.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es a esto a lo que te refieres

```js
var header = require('./header.js');

let header=new header();
```